# Array list to Collection<Object>

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm having trouble with my data structures in Java. I'm attempting to write a parameterized selenium test, as I need to test adding different data to the same field. The idea is that I read the set of data line by line from a file, and that becomes my test's input.

The example code I've found creates an object[] for the input is as follows:

```
    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[] > data(){
    Object[][] data = new Object[][] { {"1"}, {"JU"}, {"JUnit Parallel"}};
    return Arrays.asList(data);
}
```

I want to read my data from the file, as follows:

```
        @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[] > data() throws IOException{

        Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("/home/users/me/myfile"));
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (s.hasNext()){
            list.add(s.next());
        }
        s.close();
        Object[][] data = new Object[][] {list.toArray()};
        return Arrays.asList(data);
    }
```

This throws the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
at org.junit.runners.Parameterized$TestClassRunnerForParameters.createTestUsingConstructorInjection(Parameterized.java:186)
at org.junit.runners.Parameterized$TestClassRunnerForParameters.createTest(Parameterized.java:181)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:244)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:241)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:127)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

I don't understand these data structures enough to figure this out myself, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments means that the datatype you are trying to create or use has the wrong input, for instance String lol = new String("only one string is accepted", "i'm giving 2 over here") this would give the same error, try looking up what line has the problem and what datatypes are used on those lines, then look up how the datatypes work

Comment: So likely "Object[][] data = new Object[][] {list.toArray()};" doesn't do quite what I think it does?

Comment: I'm not a 100% on that, you should really just google list.toArray and Objects to see how many arguments they take and what kind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not creating a 2D array in the way that your tests need it: rather than creating an N×1 array, it creates a 1×N array.

Let's say your file has this text:

```
1
JU
JUnit_Parallel
```

Then your code would create an array of objects that looks like this

```
new Object[][] { {"1", "JU", "JUnit_Parallel"} };
```

not like this

```
new Object[][] { {"1"}, {"JU"}, {"JUnit_Parallel"}};
```

To fix this problem, change your code as followed:

```
@Parameters
public static Collection<Object[]> data() throws IOException{
    Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("/home/users/me/myfile"));
    ArrayList<Object[]> list = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
    while (s.hasNext()){
        list.add(new Object[] { s.next() });
    }
    s.close();
    return list;
}
```

Now the `IllegalArgumentException` error should go away, assuming that your parameterized test method takes exactly one parameter of type `String`:

```
@Test
public void testFindElements(String arg) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Aaaaaah, That makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Nowhere in the stacktrace you've posted does it reference your code, so the code you posted really isn't useful. It seems that this might be a JUnit issue, but as a wild guess, it might also be a problem caused by the class you are testing not having a null constructor?